# test the speed of quicksort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I read the book of Algorithm 4th edition princeton and watched the online course video. I have found two interesting things.

1. It was said in the video, if we use a cutoff like this in quicksort, we will speed up the program by 10~20%:

   if(hi - lo < CUTOFF) Insertion.sort(a);

It suggested that when we use recursive formula to divide the array a into subarray, and sort subarray recursively, we can use insertion sorting algorithm when the size of subarray is smaller than CUTOFF instead.However, when I test it with CUTOFF size 3, 7 and 10. It was not the case. It's about 10 times slower in my test data set. The data set is array of 5000 random numbers. So I guess we'd better not use insertion sorting for small size array.

2. When I trying to measure the running time of my code and compare it to the standard code from this course, i.e. the algs4.jar library. I found my time is longer, even I change my code as the standard code. Finally, I realized that even if we quicksort the same array twice ( copied the array as a1, a2), the running time of the second sorting will always be around half of the running time of the second sorting. i.e. (pseudo code):
        stopWatch sw1 = new stopWatch();
        quicksort(a1);
        print sw1.elaspedTime();

   ```
    stopWatch sw2 = new stopWatch();
    quicksort(a2);
    print sw2.elaspedTime();
   ```

Then the second one cost about half time, even they are the same algorithm and sorting the same array. I don't know why this happened. It's a very interesting phenomenon.

Comment: did you implemented quick sort by yourself or you used the build in one

Comment: I implemented by myself and compare with the code in the book. Finally, I changed my code the same as the book. The result is the same as described above

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that if you change the order of execution of tester algorithms you will get other result. Jvm need time to worm up.

Comment: Yes, this was what I did. If I switched it, the second one is always faster.

Comment: The best approach is to run one of your algorithm just to worm up the JVM than start real tests.

Answer (score 1):

Now. By theory it could be faster, but depending on what language, compiler, system, CPU you are using, it might be different. I can just gonna use your 2nd point as an example. CPU has something called cache which would hold the frequent used data to increase speed. It is very small but it is super fast, way faster than RAM. So basically the first time you ran the program, the array was initially in memory and it got into cache when there is a cache miss. When you run the same code the second time, everything is in cache already, there is no need to look it up in RAM and no cache misses, so its way faster than first run. If you would like accurate result then you might have to clear RAM clear Cache, shut down any program you are running and ect

Comment: Got you! It make sense. Thanks!